Wiring non-inverting opamp
I have an Texas Instrumentes OP07 and am trying to wire it as non-inverting amplifier.


I have made some photos.
On the "near" photo you can barely see the "orientation circle":

I was not 100% sure with dual power supply, so I made up this, see the "far" photo:

I have connected oscilloscope 1MOhm probe to out and oscilloscope ground clip to circuit ground.
On the "far" photo you can see a blue breadboard wire connected to a white wire. This is my antenna which picks up some stray 50Hz fields easily measurable without amplifier, which I then expect to be amplified.
But I don't see any signal at my oscilloscope, only 4V from power supply. I have checked a lot for loose connectons, but didn't find any. Maybe I have done something wrong?


But I don't see any signal at my oscilloscope, only 4V from power supply


The minimum operational supply for the OP-07 is 6 volts
The guaranteed usable input range is between Vneg + 2 volts and Vpos - 2 volts
The guaranteed usable output voltage is Vneg +2.5 volts to Vpos - 2.5 volts


The fix should be something like a 10 MΩ resistor connected between IN+ and 0 volts (mid-rail). The IN+ pin produced up to 4 nA of leakage current on the OP-07 and if the open circuit impedance is 1 GΩ (a lot more of course), the input will rise or fall to +/- 4 volts. 10 MΩ guarantees that the input will remain within +/- 40 mV. It maybe less of course. And, remember that the gain of 11 will magnify this input offset by 11 at the output.

In dual supply mode the minimum operational supply is 3 volts.

Yes, half of 6 volts.

What does "guaranteed usable input range" mean? The picked up 50Hz stray fields are much below 2V.

It's the range over which the input pins are guaranteed to work

I measured The picked up 50Hz stray fields before without amplifier and the were way below 2V, so should be no problem.

"The guaranteed usable output voltage is Vneg +2.5 volts to Vpos - 2.5 volts" So if i pick up 4V something is wrong? If you look at the circuit it is clear that 4V from power supply are picked up by oscilloscope. My oscilloscope has a DC filter itsfelf so no problem.

You cannot leave an input floating like that. Use a 10 Meg resistor to 0 volts at the very least.

IN- is connected via 1kOhm to ground. Should I connect the end of the antenna with 10MOhm to ground so IN+ is grounded too?

Connect IN+ to ground via 10 Meg otherwise the input bias current from that pin will leave it at an undefined and unusable DC level. Connect it at the op-amp @Hansebenger

Ok will do and report back

It works. Please add the concrete comment with the10MOhm resistor to your answer. A more sophisticated explanation why there is DC input bias current at this pin would be nice but I don't insist on it. Thanks!

Any input on any chip has a leakage current @Hansebenger
